# Is it possible to auto copy keys from ssh config to ssh agent? how?

Tags: ssh, osx, ssh-agent

I have the `~/.ssh/config` file I'm using to manage different keys from different hosts.

However, each time a new key is added, I'll need to also manually add this to ssh agent via `ssh-add` for separate reasons.

Is there a way this can be achieved automatically? if yes, how?

P.S: If it's any useful, I'm also using a macbook (osx)

Comment: I think that you are going to have to write some type of scripting to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the case you specially worded in your question would be complicated and would require some bash scripting, which I don't recommend for such simple task.

But very similar thing can be achieved using `AddKyesToAgent` option in `ssh_config`, that will basically add the keys to `ssh-agent` when it is used for the first time. This option is available since [OpenSSH 7.2](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2).